# Powershell Arrays and Refreshing

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm currently writing a script that uses get-service | select Displayname to show whats running.

However, I'm having trouble.

I'm using this:

```
function Getcurrent-AD 
{
  $Script:current_active_d = get-service | select Displayname
  $array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
  $array.AddRange($current_active_d)
  $current_output.DataSource = $array
  $objForm.refresh()
}
```

and

```
$moveright.Add_Click({

$selectedRow = $current_output.CurrentRowIndex
  if (($procid=$Script:current_active_d["$selectedRow"].displayname)) {
              write-host $procid
        }


}
)
```

to create an array and put it in a data form grid which then writes to host where I'm clicking but I can only get it to work so that it display in the console the first item selected.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$current_output.Add_Click({
    $value = $current_output.Rows[$current_output.CurrentRow.Index].Cells['DisplayName'].Value
    Write-Host $value
})
```

Comment: thanks but I'm afraid I'm getting this error - Cannot index into a null array. At C:\Temp\ADXv0.300.ps1:170 char:30 + $value = $moveright.Rows[ <<<< $moveright.CurrentRow.Index].Cells['Displa yName'].Value + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: Here are my forms: $current_output = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView - $moveright = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button - Move right is the name of the button I'm using

Comment: Cool, then consider accepting it as the answer if you think it helped you. I updated my answer with the correct control object.